# Deep links from firebase dynamic links to expo go

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

So i am using firebase dynamic links, created a link and it opens the downloadeble/production app in the playstore and appstore. And on the web it opens the URL so all that works fine.

But i am developing in an expo managed workflow. And i would like to do things with the params of the dynamic link. Display text on the screen etc.

How can i test an firebase dynamic link on the expo go app. or do i need to use an emulator for that of something else?

I already tried some things with expo-linking and i can get that to work but i dont know how to get firebase dynamic links in expo go